# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to \pi/4}{{\tan(x)}^{\tan(2x)}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I guess I should apply natural logarithm here or something like that, but I can't unterstand what to do. I shouldn't apply L'Hôpital's rule as I haven't studied it yet.

Comment: What is $tg(x)$?  Is that the tangent?

Comment: @icurays1 Yes, I fixed it

Comment: Your idea to take the logarithm is a good one.  That will bring the exponent down front, then the limit will probably be more clear.  If you're still stuck I'll submit an answer for you.

Comment: @icurays1 Still stuck. Indeed, I got an answer ($e^{-1/2}$), but it's not the one WolframAlpha gives. I made a mistake somewhere. I would like to see your calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that 
$$\tan 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}.$$
Put $\tan x=1+t$. Then as $x$ approaches $\pi/4$, $t$ approaches  $0$.

The expression we are taking the limit of becomes, under the substitution,
$$\left((1+t)^{-1/t}\right)^{(2+2t)/(2+t)}.$$
The function $(1+t)^{-1/t}$ approaches $e^{-1}$ as $t$ approaches $0$. The outer exponent $(2+2t)/(2+t)$ approaches $1$.

Answer (score 1):

*This evaluation uses L'Hôpital's rule. It was written prior to the edit to the question.*

Let $f(x)=(\tan (x))^{\tan (2x)}$. Then
$$
\log f(x)=\tan (2x)\log \left( \tan (x)\right) =\frac{\log \left( \tan
(x)\right) }{\dfrac{1}{\tan (2x)}},
$$

and by the [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi /4}\log f(x) &=&\dfrac{\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi /4}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left( \log \left( \tan (x)\right) \right) }{\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi /4}
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left( \dfrac{1}{\tan (2x)}\right) } \\
&=&\dfrac{\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi /4}\dfrac{1+\tan ^{2}x}{\tan x}}{
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi /4}\left( -\dfrac{2}{\tan ^{2}2x}-2\right) } \\
&=&\frac{2}{-2}=-1.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
So
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi /4}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi /4}e^{\log
f(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow \pi /4}\log f(x)}=e^{-1}.
$$